# Which queuing implementation is advisable if we want to keep things simple?

Tags: spring, jms, messaging, activemq-classic, queuing

our needs for a queuing solution are fairly simple, a producer needs to put things in a persistent queue and these need to be handled by a consumer. The queuing systems needs to be integrated within a Spring application and distributed on multiple tomcat hosts.

When reading through questions i see a lot of people that warn about using ActiveMQ with Spring for example so i am wondering what the alternatives are when taking simplicity, scalability and performance in mind when combined with a Spring based application.

Comment: Whatever you choose here, it will not be simple. This is a hard problem to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Sping, then integrating ActiveMQ with it is fairly easy.  The simplest solution would be to run ActiceMQ standalone and have your Tomcat applications simply communicate with it using Spring JMS (or AMQ client APIs)...

Another option is to use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).  It has great ActiveMQ support, can work with an external or embedded broker, adds many messaging/routing features and can be deployed standlone, in ActiveMQ or in Tomcat easily...good luck